# Connecting gypsum plaster pieces without space between them

Tags: materials, connections

I would like to know more about how to connect pieces of gypsum plaster effectively, without space between them. I have a few pieces of gypsum plaster (around 10 mm thickness, 20 cm width, 30 cm height) and would to connect them and form a simple box. I was thinking about some kind of steel clamps which could effectively connect the pieces, but I am not sure.

I am interested in connecting gypsum plaster board pieces without using screws e.g. without destroying the material in any way. It is about a model, which could be disassembled and reassembled again. That is why I first though about some steel clamps or some steel frames in which the parts could be inserted and removed.

Any ideas or where to look?

Answer (score 1):

Use some steel channel and have the pieces slide in and out, but you will see that this type of board will suffer damage...

The steel or aluminium channel is available at many stores...

Comment: That is what I am afraid of (damage on the edges). What kind of material similar to gypsum plaster boards would be most resistant to damage in your opinion?